# Limit only using squeeze theorem $ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)} x\,\arctan\left(\frac{1}{y-2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Someone can help me to solve this limit only using squeeze theorem

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)} x\arctan\left(\frac{1}{y-2}\right)$$

I have done the substitution:
$$ \lim_{(x,v)\to(0,0)} x\arctan\left(\frac{1}{v}\right)$$

$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{v}\right) \sim \frac{1}{v}$$

$$ \lim_{(x,v)\to(0,0)}  \frac{x}{v}$$

$$0\le \frac{|x|}{|v|}\le$$

Now I'm stucked, I don't know how to continue the inequality.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Your substitution is only correct near 0, not near $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $y\ne 2$ then
$$0\le \left|x\arctan\left(\frac{1}{y-2}\right)\right| \le \frac{\pi}{2}|x|.$$
Now squeeze.